# $q$ an odd prime and $p$ divides $1+n+\dots +n^{q-1}$. Show $p=q$ or $p\equiv 1$ mod $ q$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

$n$ is a natural number and $p$ is prime.

I have seen the question that is marked as duplicate, but it does not awnser my question.

This is what I tried: First suppose $n\equiv 1$ mod $q$. Then $1 + n+\dots n^{q-1}\equiv 0$ mod $ q$. So there's an $a$ with $ap\equiv 0$ mod $q$. From here I want to show $p=q$, but don't now how to continue.

Now suppose $n\not\equiv 1$ mod $q$.
We know $p(n-1)\mid (n^q - 1)$, so there's an $a$ with $ap(n-1) = (n^q -1)$. Using Fermat's little Theorem we see $ap\equiv 1$ mod $q$. From here I want to show $p\equiv 1$ mod $q$, but again don't know how to continue.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Here is a hint. $p|(n^q-1)$, so the order of $n$ mod $p$ must be $1$ or $q$. Those lead to the two cases in the conclusion.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!